# How to keep admin area of the website accessible by only specific devices?

Tags: web, hosting, server

Scenario :

The website is hosted on shared hosting and currently only protected with username and pass, which may be leaked by employees.

admin panel is located at `xyz.com/admin` and I want it to be accessible by only specific devices on our network and deny all other public / external access.

Since the IP address of the network is Dynamic using `.htaccess` is not possible.

Comment: I hear there are things like iptables which should do that kind of things. Also using the .htaccess you can block specific ips.

Comment: dynamic ip keeps changing , and .htaccess blocks certain ip, i want to allow only my mobile device, unfortunately which has dynamic ip

Comment: when you say `leaked by employees`, are you speaking of your shared hosting company employees? Because they can't see your passwords, they're encrypted.

Comment: Two-factor auth might be a possibility, that way if the malicious user does manage to get the password, they wouldn't have the two-factor code generating device to provide the second part of the authentication. SSL client certificates might work too. It depends on what your actual security concern is.

Comment: Following up on @FélixGagnon-Grenier 's comment, if it's data security you're after, and it's the shared hosting company employees that you're worried about, unless your data is encrypted on their servers, they'll be able to see your data anyway. Passwords are *usually* encrypted, depending on the implementation.

Comment: i have a website with username and pass, but due to competition the X-employee can give credentials to some one else and here access data on my site. so is it possible to restrict the use my website hosted on web server to be accessed only on my tablet ?

Comment: i have looked at getting MAC address and matching it every time at login, but it seems you cannot get MAC via php , rather in my experiments it has not worked. it works only if server and client is on same network.

Answer (score -1):

**Considering that the devices you want to give access to the website will be on same network Try the following code:**

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 173.194.36.3
```

replace the IP address with your network's external IP address check that by googling **what's my IP**.

save that code to `.htaccess` file on the root of your web application.

UPDATE : Having the issue of Dynamic IP install a DNS updater on the client devices and replace the ip with the host name provided by DNS updater.

[noip](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdyn.com%2Fapps%2Fupdater-windows%2F&ei=aGX4VMvHNpDbuQSO5YHIBQ&usg=AFQjCNF7YSgw8M5Xi68-gUSJ7_NXSdlWaQ&sig2=0q5F1sKJPkZAfU-gvaYjbg&bvm=bv.87519884,d.c2E) client for windows what it does is updates you dynamic ip to its host name created for you , that it will solve that issue

Comment: This won't work for a dynamic IP, which the asker stated they have.

Comment: I have updated the answer I think using Dynamic DNS updater will solve this.

Comment: i have a website with username and pass, but due to competition the X-employee can give credentials to some one else and therefore access data on my site. so is it possible to restrict the use my website hosted on web server to be accessed only on my tablet ?

Comment: Follow my answer and then setup internal firewall to block all the devices on your network from accessing your site's login page except your device . To know how to setup internal firewall pls open another question so that it can help others too. So now only your IP can access the login and due to your internal firewall only you are granted to access it.